# Image broken when appending remote html content by ajax in phonegap

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, phonegap-desktop-app

Hi everyone I'm Completely new to phonegap . I have problem with remote image loading . Actually i have build app with phonegap  desktop version for loading remote image i have to add csp in index page so i added this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';">
```

After adding above csp i got load the image in index.html page

```
<img data-rel="external" alt="ssss" src="http://example.com/1531913072.png" class="rounded-circle" id="commonUserImage" width="75" height="76"/>
```

But image not loading when loading html content appended by ajax that img tag is showing broken.

Mine app is index.html single page other pages i'm loading by ajax call to remote server and appending html content to body . everything i'm doing ajax call.

> Note I have given orgin permission * already in xml .

Thanks in advance.